# How to break from multiple instances calls of a recursive function?

Tags: java, recursion, graph

I am creating a recursive function that will find the path between two nodes in a graph. The path will only be found if a node is not duplicated. If a node is connected to two other nodes two instances of the recursive function will be created. If there is a correct path from both of them the last found path will be set instead of the first one (line this.nodePath = clonedNodePath;). How can I break from all recursive calls when a path is found and not only break from the current recursive call instance? (I don't want to throw an exception)

```
private void process(String currentNodeId, List<String> currentNodePath) {
        FlowNode currentFlowNode = modelInstance.getModelElementById(currentNodeId);

        List<String> clonedNodePath = new ArrayList<>(currentNodePath);

        if (currentFlowNode == null || clonedNodePath.contains(currentNodeId)) return;

        clonedNodePath.add(currentNodeId);

        if (currentNodeId.equals(finishNodeId)) {
            this.nodePath = clonedNodePath;
            return;
        }

        currentFlowNode.getOutgoing()
                .stream()
                .forEach(sequenceFlow -> process(sequenceFlow.getTarget().getId(), clonedNodePath));

}
```

Comment: You're using a class level variable called "finishNodeId" right?  Declare another class level variable of type `boolean` that is initially false to indicate when a path has been found.  When that flag variable is true, simply exit out of your recursive call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem lies in the iteration over the outgoing egdes.

You chose to do it with a Java8 stream, and this doesn't allow you to do an early abort (nitpicking: you can work around that "limitation", but that's clumsy).

Change that to a classical `for` loop, and your problem mostly disappears. Have your `process()` method return a boolean success indication, and inside the loop, if it gives true, return true out of this `process()` recursive call.

Or even more elegant: have the `process()` method return an `Optional<List<String>>`, either empty in case of failure, or filled with the path if successful. Then you also get rid of communicating via `this.nodePath`. And the process() method would better be named `findPath()`.

P.S. I know it's en vogue to use streams, but there are situations where they're simply not the appropriate tool.